# Get Node info in PHP Code Formatted Text Field

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7

In Drupal 7, I have a content type with a text field that's being formatted to process php. If I create an instance of that content type is there a way to get information about the node in the code?

So my text field has:

```
<?php print $node->nid; ?>
```

I get the error:

> - Notice: Undefined variable: node in eval() ...
> - Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in eval() ...

Also doing this does not work (I get the same undefined error for $nid):

```
<?php
    $node = node_load($nid);
    print_r($node);
?>
```

Is there any way to retrieve information about the node this way?

Answer (score 2):

You can call

```
$node  = menu_get_object();
```

Answer (score 0):

have you tried getting the nid from the args?

e.g.

```
if(is_numeric(arg(1))
{
    $nid = arg(1);
    $node = node_load($nid);
    print_r($node);
}
```

Maybe if you describe the problem you're trying to solve it will help. There a probably better, more manageable solutions to your problem which don't involve a php formatted textfield. Generally evaluating php like this should be a last resort only ;)

Comment: Yes. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4854912/get-nodeid-in-drupal/4855098#4855098